# How Get Each List item Validation Error in C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Put Method that at first receive a object class and now it receive a list of them.
Whe i use de ModelState.IsValid method  and get all errors i dont know witch element has the error; so i cast them as a List an try validate each one.

```
public IActionResult Put([FromBody]List<LIB_ColaboradorRegistroModeloCondicionLaboral> Colaboradores)
{
    LIB_ControlResultado oCRB = new LIB_ControlResultado();
    var adColaboradores = new List<AD_ColaboradorRegistro>();
    AD_ColaboradorRegistro adColaborador = new AD_ColaboradorRegistro();
    // HERE VALIDATES ALL MODEL BUT I DONT KNOW WITCH ELEMENT HAS THE PROBLEM
    //if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    //{
    //IEnumerable<ModelError> allErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
    //string detalle = "{";
    //foreach (ModelError item in allErrors)
    //{
    //    string newdetalle = item.ErrorMessage.ToString();
    //   detalle += " Error de Campos: " + ReemplazarRespuestas(newdetalle) + ",";
    //}
    //oCRB.Descripcion = detalle + " }";
    //}
    if (oCRB.Resultado)
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var Colaborador in Colaboradores)
            {
                adColaborador = Colaborador.Cast<AD_ColaboradorRegistro>();     
                bool valid = TryValidateModel(adColaborador);
                if (valid)
                {
                    //OK
                }
                else
                {
                    //HERE I NEED TO GET THE VALIDATION ERRORS
                    LIB_ControlResultado oa = new LIB_ControlResultado() { Rut = adColaborador.RUT , NumeroContrato = null};
                } 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }
    }
    return oCRB.Resultado ? Ok(ListaResultados) : (IActionResult)BadRequest(ListaResultados);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelState` property is `ModelStateDictionary` class which implements `IEnumerable<T>` interface. That means you can use LINQ to get invalid entries.

```
var invalidItems = ModelState.Where(ms => ms.Value.Errors.Any());

foreach (ModelState item in invalidItems)
{
    // Here you have access to item.Key which is name of the property
    // And value which is current model state for property 
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Its help!